# Progress bar alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a progress bar, and I am trying to make it so when the progress bar reaches 20% it displays a div. right now when I run it it automatically pops up. I think my problem is returning the current progress bar value. I tried doing this but was unsuccessful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Information Security Assessment</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AuditScriptAssesmentToolTest.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

 
    <!--************************************************************************ -->
 
<!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************-->

<div id="myProgress">
   <progress id='progressBar' max='100' value='0' style="background-color: red; font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;"" ><strong></strong></progress>
  </div>
 </div>
<main class="mainarea">
 

  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQOne" name="firstQOne" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

  <br>
   
  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQTwo" name="firstQOne" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
</div>

  

  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQThree" name="firstQ" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

  <br>
 
   
  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQFour" name="firstQ" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
 <br>
 </div>
 <br>
 <!-- *************************************************3333333333333333333****************************************************-->
 
 <!-- ******************************************** -->
 

<div id="alert1"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
  <span id="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>  
  <strong>Nice Job!</strong> You have completed this form.
 </div>

</main>

  <script>
 function update_progressbar() {
    var opt1 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQOne')).val() );
    var opt2 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQTwo')).val() );
    var opt3 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQThree')).val() );
    var opt4 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQFour')).val() );
    var opt5 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQFive')).val() );
    var opt6 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQSix')).val() );
    var opt7 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQSeven')).val() );
    var opt8 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQEight')).val() );
    var opt9 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQNine')).val() );
    var opt10 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQTen')).val() );

      var total = isNaN( opt1 ) ? 0 : opt1;
    if ( !isNaN( opt2 ) ) {
        total += opt2;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt3 ) ) {
        total += opt3;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt4 ) ) {
        total += opt4;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt5 ) ) {
        total += opt5;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt6 ) ) {
        total += opt6;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt7 ) ) {
        total += opt7;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt8 ) ) {
        total += opt8;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt9 ) ) {
        total += opt9;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt10 ) ) {
        total += opt10;
    }
    $("#progressBar").prop( 'value', total )

   }

$('#FirstQOne').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQTwo').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQThree').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQFour').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQFive').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQSix').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQSeven').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQEight').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQNine').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQTen').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
  </script>
  <script>
   function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('alert1').style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    
    $("#alert1").delay(600).fadeIn();
  });
});

</script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#progressBar').text(20 + '%');

    if (parseFloat($('#progressBar').text()) == 20) { // or 
           $("#alert1").delay(600).fadeIn();
    }
});
 </script>

</body>
</html>

 





 <!-- ******************************************** -->
```

This code below is the one I'm trying to change to make it so when the progress bar = 20% it will display it instead of just showing immediately "**Nice Job!** You have completed this form." appears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#progressBar').text(20 + '%');

    if (parseFloat($('#progressBar').text()) == 20) { // or 
       $("#alert1").delay(600).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Inside your document ready function you have `$('#progressBar').text(20 + '%');` which triggers your condition immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you want? placing the condition that matches 20% or more into the same function that calculates the total will trigger the alert box. Also consider using the bootstrap progress bar that comes with the distro you're using. As shown in the example below

```js
function update_progressbar() {
    var opt1 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQOne')).val() );
    var opt2 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQTwo')).val() );
    var opt3 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQThree')).val() );
    var opt4 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQFour')).val() );
    var opt5 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQFive')).val() );
    var opt6 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQSix')).val() );
    var opt7 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQSeven')).val() );
    var opt8 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQEight')).val() );
    var opt9 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQNine')).val() );
    var opt10 = parseFloat( $('option:selected', $('#FirstQTen')).val() );

      var total = isNaN( opt1 ) ? 0 : opt1;
    if ( !isNaN( opt2 ) ) {
        total += opt2;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt3 ) ) {
        total += opt3;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt4 ) ) {
        total += opt4;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt5 ) ) {
        total += opt5;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt6 ) ) {
        total += opt6;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt7 ) ) {
        total += opt7;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt8 ) ) {
        total += opt8;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt9 ) ) {
        total += opt9;
    }
    if ( !isNaN( opt10 ) ) {
        total += opt10;
    }
    
    $("#progressBar").prop( 'value', total );
    
    $("#progressBar2").prop( 'aria-valuenow', total );
    $("#progressBar2").css( 'width', total + "%" );
    
    if (parseFloat(total) >= 20) { // or 
           $("#alert1").delay(600).fadeIn();
    }
    else {
           $("#alert1").delay(600).fadeOut();
    }

   }

$('#FirstQOne').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQTwo').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQThree').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQFour').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQFive').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQSix').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQSeven').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQEight').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQNine').on( 'change', update_progressbar );
$('#FirstQTen').on( 'change', update_progressbar );

function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('alert1').style.display = "block";
}

$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#progressBar').text(20 + '%');


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AuditScriptAssesmentToolTest.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div id="progressBar2" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
  </div>
</div>


    

<div id="myProgress">
   <progress id='progressBar' max='100' value='0' style="background-color: red; font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;"" ><strong></strong></progress>
 </div>
<main class="mainarea">
 

  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQOne" name="firstQOne" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

   
  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQTwo" name="firstQOne" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
</div>

  

  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQThree" name="firstQ" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

  <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="FirstQFour" name="firstQ" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" disabled selected="selected" value="0">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="7">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="10">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

 </div>

 

<div id="alert1"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
  <span id="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>  
  <strong>Nice Job!</strong> You have completed this form.
 </div>

</main>
```